# Concatenate / join / aggregate functions in python

Tags: python, function, dictionary, pandas-groupby

I created a function for generating heatmaps and the data I feed in can be groupby by different columns and aggregated with different functions (mean, sum, count). 
Up to know I had a if-elif configuration, where the condition is to match the string of the wanted function (if fun=="mean" for example).

What I have:

```
df_ex = pd.DataFrame({"id_place":np.random.randint(20, size=133),
                    "id_center": np.random.randint(35, size=133),
                    "flow": np.random.randint(500, size=133),
                    "temperature": np.random.randint(35, size=133),
                    })
def prep_df(df,columns,variable, fun):

   columns= columns
   grouped_data = df.groupby(columns)[variable]

   if fun== 'mean':
       grouped_data = grouped_data.mean()
   elif fun == 'count':
       grouped_data = grouped_data.count()
   elif fun == 'sum':
       grouped_data = grouped_data.sum()

   return grouped_data

prep_df(df_ex,["id_place","id_center"], "flow", "mean")
```

To make the code cleaner I would like to have something like a dictionary to have only one line instead of all the lines required for the if-elif where then I could call the function of interest by feeding the function argument as a key.
Something like:

```
def prep_df(df,columns,variable, fun):
    dict_fun = {'mean': mean(),
                'count': count(),
                'sum': sum() 
                }
    grouped_data = df.groupby(columns)[variable].dict_fun[fun]
```

Things is the values aren´t function themselves, and this approach fails. 
So what I would like is call the function that are available of the groupby result to aggregate, setting the function I want passing a variable or calling a dictionary. 
Is this has a specific name please let me know so I can rename the question more accurately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your function like this:

```
def prep_df2(df, columns, variable, fun):
    assert fun in {'mean', 'count', 'sum'}
    return getattr(df.groupby(columns)[variable], fun)()
```

It takes advantage of calling a function of a module by using its name (a string). 
The reason why your dict cannot work is that you didn't assign the right function, which should be bounded inside of the module and shouldn't be called.

Comment: Hey, thanks! just a question, the assert step would be to check that the fun argument is within the plausible functions to use?

Comment: @Isa yeah, to only allow the specific methods name to pass.